# data.tables and sweep function

Tags: r, data.table

Using a data.table, which would be the fastest way to "sweep" out a statistic across a selection of columns?

Starting with (considerably larger versions of ) DT

```
p <- 3
DT <- data.table(id=c("A","B","C"),x1=c(10,20,30),x2=c(20,30,10))
DT.totals <- DT[, list(id,total = x1+x2) ]
```

I'd like to get to the following data.table result by indexing the target columns (2:p) in order to skip the key:

```
    id  x1  x2
[1,]    A   0.33    0.67
[2,]    B   0.40    0.60
[3,]    C   0.75    0.25
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that something close to the following (which uses the relatively new `set()` function) will be quickest:

```
DT <- data.table(id = c("A","B","C"), x1 = c(10,20,30), x2 = c(20,30,10))
total <- DT[ , x1 + x2]

rr <- seq_len(nrow(DT))
for(j in 2:3) set(DT, rr, j, DT[[j]]/total) 
DT
#      id        x1        x2
# [1,]  A 0.3333333 0.6666667
# [2,]  B 0.4000000 0.6000000
# [3,]  C 0.7500000 0.2500000
```

FWIW, calls to `set()` takes the following form:

```
# set(x, i, j, value), where: 
#     x is a data.table 
#     i contains row indices
#     j contains column indices 
#     value is the value to be assigned into the specified cells
```

---

My suspicion about the relative speed of this, compared to other solutions, is based on this passage from [data.table's NEWS file](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/NEWS), in the section on changes in Version 1.8.0:

> ```
> o   New function set(DT,i,j,value) allows fast assignment to elements
>     of DT. Similar to := but avoids the overhead of [.data.table, so is
>     much faster inside a loop. Less flexible than :=, but as flexible
>     as matrix subassignment. Similar in spirit to setnames(), setcolorder(),
>     setkey() and setattr(); i.e., assigns by reference with no copy at all.
>
>         M = matrix(1,nrow=100000,ncol=100)
>         DF = as.data.frame(M)
>         DT = as.data.table(M)
>         system.time(for (i in 1:1000) DF[i,1L] <- i)   # 591.000s
>         system.time(for (i in 1:1000) DT[i,V1:=i])     #   1.158s
>         system.time(for (i in 1:1000) M[i,1L] <- i)    #   0.016s
>         system.time(for (i in 1:1000) set(DT,i,1L,i))  #   0.027s
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've upgraded to data.table 1.8.0, and successfully ran the test code above. I do get an elaborate warning (won't fit in here) about coercion to double when both numerator and denominators are integer columns from data.tables. I'll edit the question to that effect.

Comment: I'm having a tough time with edits today: No line feed. Anyway, here's the code: for(j in 2:p){
      set( dt , allrows , j , dt[[j]] / denom[[2]] )
    } and for both dt and denom, columns 2 to p are integer. The warning I get is

Comment: "Warning message:
In set(dt, allrows, j, dt[[j]]/denom[[2]]) :
  Coerced 'double' RHS to 'integer' to match the column's type; may have truncated precision. Either change the target column to 'double' first (by creating a new 'double' vector length 16863 (nrows of entire table) and assign that; i.e. 'replace' column), or coerce RHS to 'integer' (e.g. 1L, NA_[real|integer]_, as.*, etc) to make your intent clear and for speed. Or, set the column type correctly up front when you create the table and stick to it, please."

Comment: --> you need to declare target columns.

Comment: You should pay close attention to those warnings.  Try out the following to see why.  `D1 <- data.table(1:5); class(D1[[1]]); set(D1, 1:5, 1L, 0.33); D1`. Compare that with what you probably wanted to see: `D2 <- data.table(as.numeric(1:5)); class(D2[[1]]); set(D2, 1:5, 1L, 0.33); D2`. And then go about converting the class of the columns you are going to sweep to `numeric` rather than `integer` (either in their initial construction, or after the fact by something like `D1[[1]] <- as.numeric(D1[[1]])`). (There might be more efficient ways to do that last operation.)

Comment: @Josh Spot on. Small improvement would be no need to pass `rr` to `set()` i.e. `set(DT, j=j, value=DT[[j]]/total)` should _plonk_ the column in and be faster than `set(DT, rr, j, DT[[j]]/total)`.

Comment: @Josh And when plonking (either with `set()` or `:=`) the new column into the column slot (instead of passing `1:nrow` as `i`), the coercion warning goes away (coercion is only necessary when updating subsets of the column).

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- Does plonking with `for(j in 2:3) set(DT, j=j, value=DT[[j]]/total)` work for you? When I try it I'm given an error telling me that "'i' is missing".

Comment: @Josh Oops - `i` needs to be `NULL` to invoke a plonk. Now fixed in 1.8.1 (by defaulting `i` to `NULL`). Tests added. Thanks for testing that!

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- Just tried that out, and it's awesome.  Love it. FWIW, I agree that `set()` might more appropriately be documented over chez `:=`.

Comment: @Josh Ok will do. Btw, since the verb _plonk_ is "chiefly British" according to dictionary, I'm waiting to see if it causes any confusion/amusement! Not to be confused with the noun.